Triple DES openssl [DES-EDE3] PHP
I tried to encrypt and decrypt 3DES using the PHP OpenSSL wrapper, but the output is still different from tripledes.online-domain-tools.com.
Encrypt
data :123456789012FFFF
Key : EC1B1F2B180F8558D512A75D2354EF049A5B81F198387B5

$encyData = openssl_encrypt(hex2bin($data), 'DES-EDE3', hex2bin($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA); 
echo bin2hex($encyData);  

Result : a63016d04154e887b84ad801a8f008ae
but if it's on the web. has the result: a63016d04154e887
Decrypt
data :1BB40C98DA97CE1C3FFB9581DAC5E6B139AB8ADC1226FE0C
Key : F088F52E62D23619D576F0293134EF8FE64E2BB758BD40D6

$decData = openssl_decrypt(bin2hex($data), 'DES-EDE3', hex2bin($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
echo bin2hex($decData); 

Result : the result is null
but if it's on the web. has the result: ec1b1f2b180f8558d512a75d2354ef049a5b81f198387b59
how does the openssl php code match the results on the web?

The website you are using applies Zero padding, while PHP/OpenSSL uses PKCS#7 padding. s. here. The length of your plaintext equals an integer multiple of the block size (8 bytes for Triple DES). In this case, with zero padding the plaintext is not padded, whereas with PKCS#7 padding it is padded with a full block. Note that in your example for encryption the key is too short (only 47 hex digits; probably missing a 9 at the end).

If you want to reproduce the result of the PHP code, you need a suitable online tool, e.g. CyberChef, which also uses PKCS#7 padding, s. here.

Since Zero padding does not pad plaintexts whose length is an integer multiple of the block size (which applies mostly, but not for all implementations), PHP/OpenSSL's default PKCS#7 padding can be disabled to reproduce the results of the web site, see here and here. However, this only works for plaintexts that fulfills the length criterion. Note that in your example for decryption there is a typo (bin2hex() must be replaced by hex2bin()).

@Topaco
Thank you very much sir. This is very helpful and my problem has been resolved
